# Add incoming querystring to all outgoing links/traffic c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string, parameter-passing

If i have a page called www.testsite.com and I link to that page using a querystring in the url, is it possible to attach that same querystring to all the outgoing links/traffic somehow?

For instance, say I link to that page like this www.testsite.com?parameter1=somevalue
And then, on that page I click a link to for instance google, and I would like the parameter to be passed so the url would be www.google.com?parameter1=somevalue.

I know how to do this manually, but is there someway it can be appended to the url automatically? Like catch the outgoing request before happening and add the parameter?

Thanks!

Eric

Answer (score 3):

you could do this pretty simply with javascript or javascript using jQuery

```
$("a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location = $(this).attr("href") + window.location.search;
});
```

that should get you started

if you wanted a non-jQuery solution you can look into binding events using javascript only

http://www.digimantra.com/tutorials/change-onclick-function-anchor-tag-javascript/

http://forums.techarena.in/software-development/1308647.htm

Comment: Rather than setting window.location, you can modify the href attribute on the link itself and lose the call the `preventDefault`. It's slightly nice because setting window.location isn't *quite* the same as clicking a link - for example, the referrer header isn't passed.

Comment: I considered doing this but I wasn't sure that the non-jQuery click event wouldn't have already happened before the href was manipulated. In that case maybe it would be best to do this href appending once the page has finished loading.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement an intercepting filter through an httpmodule which modifies the html you emit back to the client.  For more details see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649096.aspx

And a few more examples:
[Http Response Filter](http://aspnetresources.com/articles/HttpFilters)
[SO: Get HTML content for modification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333287/httpmodule-get-html-content-or-controls-for-modifications)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a central location where you output the outgoing links, you will have to do this manually (possibly the visual studio search/replace can help here, but I would be careful as you may end up changing links you didn't want to).

Answer (score 0):

You can use following to use Query String parameters
You can loop through all your query string parameters like this

```
int loop1, loop2;
// Load NameValueCollection object.
NameValueCollection coll = Request.QueryString; 

// Get names of all keys into a string array. String[] arr1 = coll.AllKeys; 

string parameters = "";

for (loop1 = 0; loop1 < arr1.Length; loop1++) 
{

  parameters += Server.HtmlEncode(arr1[loop1]) + "=" + coll.GetValues(arr1[loop1]);

  for (loop2 = 0; loop2 < arr2.Length; loop2++) 
  {
    parameters += Server.HtmlEncode(arr2[loop2]);

  } 
}
```

its just basic idea. But you can loop through parameters without knowing the names.